# Rails. Permit text, validate it, make array and save to postgres. How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Rails form with textarea. User puts text spltted by comma, then submit to server, where data validates, splits to array and writes to postgres database.

But there is null array in callback before_validation. Here's it:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(user_params)
    # show profile
  end
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :nickname,
      :password,
      {tags:[]})
  end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_validation :tags_must_be_list

  def tags_must_be_list
    p tags ####### here is tags is empty [], but need to be text
    errors.add(:tags, "is not list")
  end
```

What's wrong?

Comment: can you paste the development logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying that the tags are supposed to be an array:

```
params.require(:user).permit(
  :nickname,
  :password,
  {tags:[]}) # <--------- `:tags` is supposed to be an array
```

but the tags are coming in as a single CSV string rather than an array so presumably they're being filtered out because a string is not an array.

There are various options:

1. Use some JavaScript to split the string into individual tags on the client and rewrite the form (using JavaScript) to submit individual `tags[]` parameters rather than a single `tags` string.
2. Say `permit(:nickname, :password, :tags)` and then split the tags into an array in the controller:

   ```
   user = user_params
   user[:tags] = user.delete(:tags).to_s.split(/\s*,\s*/)
   @user.update(user)
   ```
3. Provide your own `User#tags=` method to split the string before storing the tags (or maybe a `before_validation` hook to arrayify the tags if they're not an array already). You'd need the `permit` change from **2** here as well and I'm not sure what AR would do to your string before your `before_validation` hook ran, the `tags=` override should work sensibly though.

I'd probably go with **2** but many people would consider that heresy and bloat the model with **3** instead.

Comment: Thank you, second method seems to work. But what about third? it's looks logical, but tags param is empty in before_validation hook

Comment: You'd have to combine the `permit` change in 2 with the stuff in 3. I'm not sure how we'll that would work though, AR might try to arrayify the string behind your back and make a mess if things.